# Unexpected output when printing specific Row

Tags: r

when I do this command I get an unexpected output. Why am I getting Row 354 even though in my code I put row 350?

`fifa_new[c(110,350), c(2,10)]`

Output:

```
      Name                Preferred.Foot
 110 DiegoOliveira          Right         
 354      J.Howson          Right
```

Comment: Hi. Can you provide the full code please?

Comment: I cleaned the data set and removed all rows that had a missing field. Is this why it isn't working?

Comment: The rownames probably got assigned sometime before you removed rows with missing fields and now, like joran mentioned, they are no longer a continuous sequence of numbers. If you do `fifa_new$row_num <- 1:nrow(fifa_new)` you'll see that you are getting correct results.